# how to use leaks/iprofiler tool in osx

Tags: macos, memory-leaks

I am trying to use leaks tool in osx for detecting memory leaks in C++ code I have.I am executing as below:

```
leaks <pid>
```

but I couldn't get the way like valgrind does (I.e) collecting the reports till I end the process.With above command, leaks tool terminates in few seconds reporting no leak. I am missing something on how to use this tool. Anybody has any suggestions?

Also, my requirement is to get some memory leak detection in macbook for an application from command line tool like valgrind.So, I am going with leaks tool. If anyone has any other tool known, please let me know.